# Render 404 page when route is incorrect or param is missing in url. React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

Below is my url : - 
http://local.abc.com/pages/red/4

red and 4 is param , if it is unavailable or url is improper i want to redirect to 404 page.

for this i have added below route in routes.jsx

1 ] Routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import App from 'layout/app'
import Home from 'pages/home'
import Wagers from 'containers/wagersContainer'
import NotFound from 'pages/notFound'

const ROUTES = (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/wagers(/:trackCode)(/:raceNum)" component={Wagers} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
  </Route>
)
export default ROUTES
```

In this file I have added notfound component route.

Below is my app.jsx

2 ] App.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from 'layout/navbar'
import Footer from 'layout/footer'
import LoginPopup from 'common/popups/loginPopup'
import { Router, browserHistory, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'

export default class App extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
    let emptyArr = [null, "undefined", '']
    console.log(this.props.children.params)
    if(this.props.children.params && !_.every(_.values(this.props.children.params))) {
        browserHistory.push('/notFound');
    }
}

render() { 
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="pageData">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
            <Footer />
            <LoginPopup />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

This is main root component.

and below is my index.jsx

3 ] Index.jsx

```
require('./main.js');

import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, browserHistory, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'


import ROUTES from './routes';
let store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
       <Router history={browserHistory} routes={ROUTES} />
   </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('app')
```

);

When i write wrong url like http://local.abc.com/randommmm

Then it is rendring 404 page but if i miss some params then it is not returning 404.what should i do to handle notfound url.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are saying if you do /wagers/3  and miss a parameter, you do not go 404?

Comment: @EdH Yes correct. do i needto handle this in every component ? but how

Comment: I suspect that React router just marks the missing param as undefined. Why not just change your window.location.hash to #/junk or something to make it go 404 if your are missing params?

Comment: I can't make it # , they want  '#' less url

Comment: Can we handle it in component